# User able to access Admin role page - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've been using Spring Security today for registration / login and still getting to grips with it.

My configuration is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/viewGamers").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/gameLibrary").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/gamer/home")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

}
```

from this I read that if you go to `/admin/anything` you MUST have an `ADMIN` role assigned to you.  Is that correct?

I've no logic checks in the controllers that handle it and was a little surprised when a generic non-admin role user was able to go to the `/admin/home` page.

I've added a new role in the DB, ensured this user has that role associated to it, yet it can still access the admin page, is this correct?

I've run some printlns and can confirm the roles are correct.  Have I made a mistake in the config or do I *need* the additional logic of `if (user.role != "Admin") { send elsewhere }` in the admin/home controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in your configuration, you should start your security configuration from more restricted ones to less restricted.
 so change the order to:

```
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/viewGamers").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/gameLibrary").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // this will allow everything that passes all above cnofigs
```

notice I removed `.anyRequest().authenticated()` as `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` was included, you can replace it if you want all your requests to be authenticated instead.